# Decrement on click button ReactJS JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, axios

Attempting to decrement quantity when a button is clicked. Should I use axios.put or patch and what properties should I assign to the button function?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://rapidapi.com/blog/put-vs-patch/) resource explain the differences, but to put it simply:

- PUT overwrites the entire resource, meaning that if you have a Point resource with `{ x: 5, y: 4 }` and you want to change y to 2, you need to send the whole Point resource `{ x: 5, y: 2 }` to update it. If you send just `{ y: 2 }`, your entity will be overwritten to just that. You need to send all the fields, even if you won't modify their values.
- PATCH only modifies parts of the resource, so you don't have to send all the fields, just the ones you want.

tl;dr You want PATCH to modify the quantity. I'd imagine sending a PUT request for a chat server where you want to edit a message, or, in general, for small entities, or, if the whole entity is available on the client side, e.g. updating a profile.

As for your button click, it's a different question and should be asked separately (with more details, too)